# How to update a state without re-rendering using useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, render

I have a function `onCondChange` which gets called whenever user changes value in the `TextField`.

```
const onCondChange = (conds) => {
    updateState({
      ...state,
      a: { ...state.a, conds },
      b: ++state.b,
    })
  }
```

Here, I'm adding conds object inside a, something like this

```
"a": {
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "conds": "{\"rules... (something)..."}"
    }
```

Here is the useState hook:-

```
const [state, updateState] = useState({
    temp: false,
    temp2: true,
    a: {
      status: test ? '' : ACTIVE
    },
    b: 0,
  });
```

The problem is that whenever I change the value in TextField, `onCondChange` is called and it creates another duplicate object and updates `a` by adding `conds` in it. This makes re-render the component which I want to stop. How should I add the `conds` object without re-rendering?
The problem is that TextField loses its focus due to the re-render. When I comment the line `a: { ...state.a, conds }` the focus is not lost but then I'm unable to add the `conds` object inside `a`

Comment: why do you think *"This makes re-render the page"*? - it re-rendered the component, **not** the page, if the virtual DOM deemed it not to have been changed. Components re-rendering is not an issue unless it happens way too much in relation to actual rendering needs.

Comment: Issue/question is unclear. Can you provide more concrete code examples and example state? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) This is mainly how React works... update state, trigger rerender.

Comment: "The problem is that TextField loses its focus due to the re-render. When I comment the line `a: { ...state.a, conds }` the focus is not lost but then I'm unable to add the `conds` object inside `a`" - I guess we need to see the component holding this state and rendering the text field to provide any more help why it may be losing focus.

Comment: *"The problem is that TextField loses its focus due to the re-render."* That is not normally the case, normally re-rendering doesn't affect focus. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Separately: Because you're updating state based on the current value of state, in general you should prefer using a callback, not specifying the update directly, since your code could close over a stale copy of `state`. So `updateState(state => ({...state, a: {...state.a, conds }, b: state.b + 1}));` Also note I changed `++state.b` to `state.b + 1` -- [do not modify state directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). `++` modifies the operand you use it on.

Answer (score -1):

If your problem is losing focus of the text field and not re-rendering.
Then you can set focus by using `useRef()` hook.
Click here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref for more information.

```
function TextField() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  // you must give dependacy array to useEffect.
   useEffect(()=>{
    inputRef.current.focus();
  })
 return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputRef} type="text" />
    </>
  );
}
```